# javascript - remove element

Tags: javascript, html

My question is rather elementary, but I do not understand why, in the following code, on button click only button dissapears, instead of the whole div:

```
<script>
    function remove(id) {
        //get the element node
        element = document.getElementById(id);

        //remove the element from the document
        document.removeChild(element);
    }
</script>

<div id="intro" class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Your Offline Web Dictionary!</h1>
    <p class="lead">

    <div class="controls">
        <input class="span7 " type="text" placeholder=" " name="key">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onclick="remove(intro)">
            Dictionary Search
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMEVd/69)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the button element has a remove property so that is called instead of your remove function. And also the string thing.

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onclick="window.remove('intro');console.log(this.remove);">
    Search
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HMEVd/76/

Comment: +1 Yes, it is pretty good explanation. Thanks a lot!! I will accept it within few minutes.

Comment: Why would the button's `remove` get called? Is there some implicit `with` in action? And where is this `remove` coming from? It's not a specified DOM method.

Comment: Well I saw this behaviour a while back and never really questioned it.

Comment: This certainly seems to be correct (look in the console): http://jsfiddle.net/HMEVd/78/

Comment: Yet another example of why using DOM0 handlers is a Bad Idea(tm). (And the implicit `with` on the element in the `onclick` generated function is coming back to me...)

Answer (score 2):

Two problems. Firstly, `intro` should be a string, not an identifier, so use `remove('intro')` in your onclick.

Second, `document.rwmoveChild` is incorrect. `removeChild` should be called on the parent of the element you are removing. It is common to use:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: All quite correct, but it doesn't answer the question the OP asked: Why is the button, not the div, disappearing?

Answer (score 1):

`intro` should be sent to the function as a string rather than a variable, i.e, `'intro'`

Also, you must rename your function, for example, `removeById` instead of `remove`. Then it works perfectly.

The function `remove` actually does something completely different. (Your function is not even invoked when it is named `remove` as you can see by putting an alert message into it.)

```
function removeById(id) {
        //get the element node
        element = document.getElementById(id);

        //remove the element from the document
        document.removeChild(element);
}

...
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onclick="removeById('intro')">
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the symptom the OP quoted: *"on button click only button dissapears, instead of the whole div"*